# Rails 4 - Params from Paperclip upload comes as string Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, parameters

I can't get paperclip to upload jpeg file to my user model. My form is not based on user model because I am updating other tables from that form as well.
The problem is I think, the params. They come only as a filename (see `avatar`):

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ieiTHf191a/OCVf5x+xJhel47Sjp7CZUVxkv0xZUoIx1tjisEpLrJqWD3pjApZePwMDx12EovQNev4hZ5ruaHg==",
 "user"=>{"name"=>"Another",
 "avatar"=>"bla-bla.jpg",
 "description"=>"wjhdakjhsjklhdjkahl",
 "location"=>"asljdjklashlkhaklsdhlkashdkaklshdlkas"},
 "commit"=>"Save changes",
 "multipart"=>"true",
 "id"=>"99"}
```

My `users_controller` has this update action:

```
def update
    user = User.find_by(id: current_user.id)
    user.update(location: safe_params[:location],avatar: safe_params[:avatar])
    user.set_description(safe_params[:description])
    user.set_name(safe_params[:name])
    redirect_to user_path(user)
  end

...

private

  def safe_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :description, :location, :avatar)
  end
```

The other stuff like `user.set_description` is actually a method on my `User` model that sets stuff on other table. It is just handy to have.

My `User` model has this in it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :events
  has_many :contents

  has_attached_file :avatar, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

And finally my form that I'm using in my view:

```
<h1><%= @user.name %></h1>

<%= form_tag({controller: "users", action: "update", multipart: true}, method: "patch") do %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag "Name" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'user[name]', @user.name, id: :user_name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag "Avatar" %>
        <%= file_field_tag 'user[avatar]', id: :user_avatar, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag "Description" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'user[description]', @user.description, id: :user_description, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= label_tag "Location" %>
        <%= text_field_tag 'user[location]', @user.location, id: :user_location, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
        <%= submit_tag "Save changes", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

I don't expect anyone to give me quick fix. My suspicion is probably the form is set up weirdly. I'm also using Devise if that is useful info. Also, the paperclip is set up to have default avatar, so there is already an image on the user model, I am just trying to update it.

The whole error says:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in UsersController#update
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so my problem was a very simple one. I didn't specify `class` on my form. I added `class: 'edit_user'` in my view since I'm using verb `PATCH` to update database.